# Can I use ls -R to show up to 2 folder depth?

Tags: directory, ls

I have a folder tree that looks like this

```
main/                             
main/34532-23423632-2354/what-i-want/sth/other/blah-blah            
main/54634-56345634-3422/what-i-want/sth/
....
main/54356-34225675-2345/what-i-want/
```

I want it to show the tree up to the folder what I want. Because the folders sth, other and so on contain many other things that are useless.

I just want to see what's inside each folder named xxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxx.

Is there any way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to display only a list of filenames and directory names, `tree` command is very convenient.

This is not installed by default, you have to install this:

```
sudo apt-get install tree
```

Then, you can see the tree structure by using the below command:

```
tree -L 2 main/
```

option `-L` : will set the directory depth number.

**Example screenshot:**

[image]

Answer (score 16):

Use wildcards for your search like

```
ls /main/*/*/
```

That will list with a search depth of 2. User more wildcards for deeper search.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot specify recursion depth in ls, but instead you can use the following:

```
find -maxdepth 2 -type d -ls
```

*Courtesy:* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509624/limit-depth-for-recursive-file-list-in-linux

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
find -maxdepth 2 -ls
```

Comment: This will list files, which is often not desirable.  Preceding "-ls" with "-type d" will improve this answer.